# Change gcc/binutils --prefix

Tags: gcc, prefix, binutils

I once build and installed gcc and binutils with a wrong prefix (`--prefix=/home/.../usr`) passed to the configure script.

Now I reconfigured, rebuilt and reinstalled gcc and binutils with the right prefix (`--prefix=/usr`), however compiling always fails with:

```
$ /bin/ld: cannot find /home/../usr/lib/libc.so.6
```

Of course I could symlink the libraries in order to get it working, but I would like to know in which file these paths are saved and how I can change them.

Comment: What does your `/etc/ld.so.conf` say?

Comment: And when compiling with `gcc -v` what does that say? Also, don't forget to run `ldconfig`

Comment: I suggest running `ldd /bin/ld`; it probably is looking for the C library in the wrong place.  Until you can re-rebuild it (and re-reinstall it), it is likely to continue to look in the wrong place.  As a temporary band-aid, create a symlink in the 'wrong' place that points to `/lib/libc.so.6`.  That might well let it work sufficiently to be going on with.  Be very, very careful about replacing the system's own compiler tools; I've never risked it, and always install my own versions in separate directories (e.g. in `/usr/gnu` or `/usr/gcc`). If you overwrite the system build, back it up first.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch: gcc -v prints the right prefix (--prefix=/usr).

Comment: @favoretti: I have no file /etc/ld.so.conf there's just an empty directory /etc/ld.so.conf.d/

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: I shoud have said that the system is a raspberry pi for which I build my own root fs, so I didn't replace an existing gcc. ldd /bin/ld says: $libz.so.1 => /usr/lib/libz.so.1 (0x401d1000)
$ libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x400d4000)
$ libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x4008b000)
$ libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x401ec000)
$ /lib/ld-linux.so.3 (0x40056000)
Symlinking works, however I would like to have a "clean" system

Comment: I can't help very much more — I'm sorry.  I only ever expected the symlink to be a transitional stage while you used the existing ('flawed') build to rebuild `bin-utils` with your preferred locations.  However, I've not built for Raspberry Pi (nor, indeed, have I built bin-utils for a few years now), so I'm not sure what to suggest.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I cross compiled all these progams. However even a native build of gcc on the Raspberry did not solve the problem. Anyway, thank your for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now I reconfigured, rebuilt and reinstalled gcc and binutils with the right prefix (--prefix=/usr), however compiling always fails with:
>
> $ /bin/ld: cannot find /home/../usr/lib/libc.so.6

You probably have not rebuilt and re-installed libc, and the error comes from it.

On Linux, `libc.so` is a linker script, similar to this:

```
/* GNU ld script
   Use the shared library, but some functions are only in
   the static library, so try that secondarily.  */
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf64-x86-64)
GROUP ( /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a  AS_NEEDED ( /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 ) )
```

I bet your `libc.so` has `/home/../usr/lib/libc.so.6` in it.